# KinectJS drag image demo not working in latest chrome version

Tags: google-chrome, kineticjs

I am having a similar issue on my project but was able to reproduce it on the kinectjs demo site. The following page works on IE but the latest version of Chrome (ver. 26.0.1410.43) the drag and drop features no longer work.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-an-image-tutorial/

Hopefully, the issue can be identified so we can fix my environment as well.

Thanks

Comment: So the demo site uses 4.3.1-beta2 version of Kinetic.js. The latest 4.4.0 did not work but 4.3.3 worked for our solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an application i built and updating to the latest version of kineticJs solved my problem. (4.4.0)

Answer (score 0):

I got problems with this demo too, on Android's 4.1.x native browser. On Chrome mobile and other browsers, it works like a charm. On native browser, right after the dragstart, the image goes to top left corner and stays there until i redraw the layer.